# Is there a standard for converting a WebSocket request into an HTTP request on the server?

Tags: javascript, http, rest, websocket

I'm pretty new to WebSockets and this may be completely insane. If so, please let me know what I *should* be doing instead.

The idea is that I'd like to have a WebSocket connection in the browser that ultimately interfaces with a database. Because the db shouldn't be exposed to the browser there would be, of course, a server layer in between that takes in the WebSocket message and then converts that into something like a POST, or DELETE request. The server would then pass that message along to the database.

So the question is: Is there some kind of standard for translating WebSocket messages into HTTP requests?

I found one blog post where the guy made sure his WebSocket messages from the browser came in the form `{"method":"POST","content":"foo"}` so they could be understood with normal JSON parsing.  Is something like this ok or is there a more acceptable "right way."

Comment: Since you have to use HTTP to even start a websocket connection (known as a HTTP Upgrade Request), why not just use HTTP directly?

Comment: Good question. It's because I've got a really cool functionally reactive system going on the front end and I'd prefer to see updates in real time as the server pushes them out rather than have to incrementally poll for new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is not only ok, it is the only way. You need a protocol in order to communicate between server and client (otherwise how would a server/client understand what you want from it?). Whatever you choose it will be fine (you can even use standard HTTP over WebSockets). Creating your own protocol (like with the example you came up with) is perfectly fine as well. I prefer JSON-based protocols because it is easy to work with them (JSON parsers are built-in or easily available in most known lanugages)

Comment: Ok, fantastic.  I just didn't know if there was already an established correct protocol.  Thanks!